# Every Incremental build takes over 40 secs on Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, linker, ld, build-time

Though no code is changed, every incremental build takes over 40 secs, which I believe is too long. None of my apps has taken so long.

Out of the 40 secs, "Ld" takes most of its time: 31 secs.

I know Ld is a linker of Xcode, but I have no idea why linking takes so long. 
Would you advise me the potential reasons of this problem so that I can come up with actions?

[image: Build timing summary]